# Is it necessary to release memory for a string variable defined inside a function in C++?

Tags: c++, string

**Problem description:**

It is needed in C to delete the allocated memory for a pointer to an array
`char *` (how we can define string in C).

**My question:**

I am wondering if it is also necessary for C++ string types.

*For example:*

Let's say I have a function which is responsible for converting all uppercase characters to lowercase like below.

```
string convertToLowerCase(string str) {
  string res = str;
  for (int i=0; i<str.length();++i) {
    res[i]= tolower(str[i]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

- After calling this function for comparing two strings, I do not need
  to de-allocate the return string variable of the `convertToLowerCase`
  function on the caller side.
- My understanding is that the memory
  de-allocation is done in C++ string type.
- Please correct me if I am
  wrong.

Comment: If you didn't explicitly allocate something with `new` or `malloc`, you don't need to explicitly _deallocate_ anything either. Conversely, if you _do_ explicitly allocate something, you _must_ explicitly deallocate it.

Comment: ***My assumption is that the memory de-allocation in done in C++ String type*** You are correct.

Comment: In general, if you see code deleting a `std::string`, or any [library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), approach the code from the assumption that it's wrong and start looking for bugs. There might not be any, and the a dynamically allocated container is sometimes justified, but the vast majority of the time it's a sign of a troubled design. I consider it a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Aside, as `str` is passed by value (thus a copy/move from the caller), `res` is pointless; just modify `str` and return it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, That is true.
But this is not related to my question :)
I intentionally created a new string (res) to make the question clear whether the newly created string should be deleted or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> string type,defined as char *

`char*` is merely a pointer. It is not a string. It can point to a character within a string though.

> I understand in C we need to delete any memory allocation for string type

You (usually) need to deallocate all memory that you allocate, regardless of what type you allocate the memory for. This applies to both languages.

> My assumption is that the memory de-allocation in done in C++ String type, but please correct me if i am wrong.

Your assumption is not wrong. Well designed classes deallocate what they allocate.

Answer (score 1):

Setting compiler optimizations aside for the moment for simplicity, in C++, you can assume that when an object, like an instance of a string, goes out of scope, its destructor is called. If the class of which that object is an instance is well-written, then you can assume that any memory allocated by the class will be freed in the calling of destructor. The returned object will be copied into the variable at the calling site of the function before the destructor is called on the returned object.

Compiler optimizations such as RVO can cause different behavior, but this is I think a good conceptual starting point.